# Scripting layer with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im having abit of an issue with  C# / asp.net website development - i need to have some parts of my site to be handling logic and calculations which i would like to seperate from a compiling word - just like if i had it in PHP i can on the fly edit textfiles and instant have a result, whereas with asp.net i need to get the whole compiler environment up running to change code and restart server etc.

What model could be suggested to pull parts out in something that serverside can be edited on the fly with no visual studio up running ? I was thinking something like python or combined with php maybe ? But not sure how that actually works i would like not to work with this layer through visual studio.

What would be the way on asp.net ?

Comment: That is already available in ASP.NET, both the old WebForms and MVC. You don't need to `get the whole compiler environment up running etc` either. If you want compiled code, just compile your project, with `msbuild` in .NET Framework or `dotnet build` in .NET Core.  Nor do you need VIsual Studio. You can use Visual Studio Code, essentially a port of the Electron editor with a ton of extensions

Comment: Compilation is also used in PHP because it results in *FASTER* sites, that take a lot less time to warm up. That's VERY important when you use load balancing and want to add/remove machines from the farm. It's also a lot easier to *deploy* such sites.

Comment: BTW editing in production is frowned upon in PHP too. It's OK while developing but a sure way to bring the site down in a most embarassing way when done in production. Not that ASP.NET developers don't modify their `aspx` or `cshtml` views when they get lazy, and they only have to make that one change to a single server. Unless it crashes of course

Comment: If you want a simpler model than MVC, you can use [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Razorpages is interesting thanks - i understand that irs better to build and compile but i would like a layer thats easy to modify both in the testing phase but also to be configurable ( ex wants to add calculations easily ) where it cannot come by a compiler or building phase.

Comment: @Tpchmate why not? That's how web sites are being built for the last 20 years. Configurable means that you *don't* have to modify the web pages in order to change how they behave. You change a configuration file or configuration data in a database. That's also built-in. If you need to modify the web pages, your site is the exact **opposite** of configurable

Comment: @Tpchmate if you mean that you want to render different HTML for different data, that's not configuration. ASP, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, all allow you to write code in the views themselves. Better yet, you can use databinding and templates so you *don't* have to. These are the same features that later appeared in Backbone and Knockout.JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the--net-framework)

With this, you can build inline code in aspx file, and the code block will be execute during page rendering